# Unable to extract text after matching a phrase in input string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a URL from a string. The input is something like this:

```
const str = `/div><img src="https://server_url.com/assets/image.jpg&size=800x600"></img><div`;
```

But when I try to get the URL, I get `null`:

```
const match = str.match(/https:\/\/server[a-zA-Z]{1,}&size=[0-9]{1,}x[0-9]{1,}/g) // returns null
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                              I do this, because the size is not always 800x600
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Doing just the following works:

```
const match = str.match(/https:\/\/server/g)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not matching all the possible the characters after server.

In Javascript you can write `[0-9]{1,}` as `\d+` to match 1 or more digits.

```
https:\/\/server[^&\s]*&size=\d+x\d+
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5P3NhR/1)

If there can be more parameters, you can exclude matching the `"` instead:

```
https:\/\/server[^\s"]*&size=\d+x\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkVObl/1)

Comment: I always wondered how to handle digits like that. Can I ask you if this is ok (using `.*`) or it is prone to errors? `https:\/\/server.*&size=\d+x\d+`

Comment: @GrafiCode I have added a second pattern to not cross matching `"` If you use `.*` then it will first match until the end of the string, and then backtrack to match the next part in the pattern. The dot can also match a space or `"` so it can overmatch if there are more texts/chars to the right that match out of the scope that you want it to be.